# how can i make sure that all the result in sphinx have a specific tag without making database calls?

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

How can i make sure that all the result in sphinx have a specific type without making database calls?
example:

```
|id|tag|name|
|1|media| movie|
|2|media| picture |
|3|text|media tech|
```

if i search for the word "media" the 3rd row will not be return because in the tag field it is text instead of "media", it is important that i don't work with db calls because the overhead would be huge.

Comment: given your reaction to John Corbett's answer: what is your Perl-related question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want your index to only contain the 'media' type rows? Just adjust your WHERE clause in the SQL query

```
WHERE .... AND type='media'
```

Comment: mmmm i don't want my index to contain only media type, actually this is more like a tag field.

Answer (score 1):

if you're doing this in perl, you could just use regex. Try this one

```
/\|.*?\|[^|]*media/
```

Comment: where do you suggest should i do that?

Comment: Well I assumed that you were doing this in a perl script because you had perl as tag. you would just loop through all of the lines in your result and do something like `$line =~ /\|.*?\|[^|]*media/` to see if it has the type "media"

Answer (score 0):

String attributes can be used for this
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-attr-string

Attributes are returned with the results. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#attributes

If you still want to be able to 'search' the column too, use 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-field-string

to make the column BOTH a field and an attribute.

- **Fields** - full-text searchable - as they are fully indexed.
- **Attributes** - can be used filtering/sorting/grouping and included in results.